# Error C2678 C++ A* Pathfinding

Tags: c++, a-star

I'm currently working on implementing the A* pathfinding algorithm in C++. I tried to run my code to see if the display grid function was working but got the C2678 error: binary '<': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const Coord' (or there is no acceptable conversion).

I know that my program is messy and probably not efficient at all however i was trying to get a basic version working before optimising. Is the error because I'm trying to output a boolean value of a Coord structure?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

using std::chrono::milliseconds;
using std::chrono::duration_cast;
using std::this_thread::sleep_for;

typedef std::chrono::steady_clock the_clock;

struct Location {
    int g = 0; // Distance covered so far 
    int h = 0; // Estimate of distance to goal
    float f = 0; // Estimated cost of the complete path
    bool walkable = 0; // 0 = Walkable, 1 = Wall
};

// Structure 
struct Coord {
    int x;
    int y;
    Location location;
};

// Declare size of grid
#define WIDTH 10
#define HEIGHT 10

typedef Location Array[HEIGHT][WIDTH];
Location grid[HEIGHT][WIDTH]; // Create an array of locations

void displayGrid() {
    /* Displays the Grid to the console! */
    system("CLS");
    for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++) {
            std::cout << grid[y][x].walkable;
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    sleep_for(milliseconds(100)); // Visual delay
}

void initialiseGrid() {
    /* Fills the Grid array with values */
    srand((unsigned)time(0));

    for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++) {
            grid[y][x].walkable = 0; 
    }
}

/* Test grid */
grid[4][2].walkable = 1;
grid[5][2].walkable = 1;
grid[4][3].walkable = 1;
grid[5][3].walkable = 1;
grid[4][5].walkable = 1;
grid[5][5].walkable = 1;
grid[4][6].walkable = 1;
grid[5][6].walkable = 1;
}

void Astar(Coord startPoint, Coord endPoint) {
    /**/
    std::set<Coord> closedSet = {}; // Nodes that do not have to be considered again
    std::set<Coord> openSet = {}; // Nodes still to be considered to find the shortest path

    Coord currentNode; // Current node
    currentNode.x = startPoint.x;
    currentNode.y = startPoint.y;
    currentNode.location.g = 0; // 0 Distance from starting point

    openSet.insert(currentNode); // Insert starting node

    while (openSet.empty() == false) { // Loop while open list is not empty

        for (std::set<Coord>::iterator it = openSet.begin(); it != openSet.end(); it++) { // Iterate through each element in the open set to find the lowest F value
            if ((*it).location.f < currentNode.location.f) { // Check if iterator f value is smaller than the current value
                currentNode = *it; // Update the current node
            }
        }

        openSet.erase(currentNode); // Drop from the open set since been checked
        closedSet.insert(currentNode); // Add to the closed set
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // Set start and end points
    Coord start;
    start.x = 3;
    start.y = 3;
    Coord end;
    end.x = 5;
    end.y = 6;

    initialiseGrid(); // Put -1 (empty) in

    // Start timing
    the_clock::time_point startTime = the_clock::now();

    // Stop timing
    the_clock::time_point endTime = the_clock::now();

    // Compute the difference between the two times in milliseconds
    auto time_taken = duration_cast<milliseconds>(endTime - startTime).count();

    displayGrid();

    std::cout << "That took: " << time_taken << " ms" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: I don't see the implementation of operator< in the code you provided.

Comment: [`std::set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/) requires elements with a *strict weak ordering*. You `Coord` struct doesn't provide any ordering operations (no specialization of `std::less`, no `operator<()`). Hence `std::set` doesn't know how to compare your `Coord` objects and croaks.

Comment: ***Is the error because I'm trying to output a boolean value of a Coord structure?*** No. The error is because you are using `std::set<Coord>`. @dhke explained this pretty well.

Comment: So I should create an ordering function or overload the < operator inside the structure? @dhke

Comment: @BetaParticle Since `Coord` is probably never part of a class hierachy `bool operator<(const Coord &const) const` seems fine. `std::less` more or less exists as C++' workaround for all kinds of coercion and commutation problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to solve the issue with `std::set` requiring a strict-weak-ordering and your `Coord` class is to provide an `operator <` comparing the `x` and `y` values in `Coord`, and returning whether one `Coord` is less than another `Coord` using these values.

You can do this with [std::tie](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie)

```
#include <tuple>
//...
struct Coord {
    int x;
    int y;
    Location location;
    bool operator <(const Coord& c) const 

    // returns true if this->x and this->y < c.x and c.y, false otherwise
    { return std::tie(x,y) < std::tie(c.x,c.y); }  
};
```

The `std::tie` compares the `x` components, then if equal, compares the `y` components.  The result of the comparison is returned (either `true` if the first set of x,y components is less than the second set of x,y components, or `false` otherwise).

[Live Example here](http://ideone.com/33NhbT)

Comment: Thank's for your help Paul, it's working as expected  now.  This was my first time dealing with strict-weak-ordering so I didn't have a clue what was going on. Appreciate it!